# why can't I assign 1.2 value to float variable in C#? I did the same in C and C++, and it worked

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, double

why can't I assign 1.2 value to float variable in C#? I did the same in C and C++, and it worked.

```
class Program
{
    private readonly int a = 20;
    private readonly float b;      

    public Program(float tmp)
    {
        b = tmp;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj1 = new Program(1.2);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

It gives error can not convet double to float.
Why is so isn't 1.2 float value?

Comment: In C and C++, 1.2 is double too. It'll be truncated down to float. Maybe there will be a warning

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`1.2` is a `double` (8 bytes).
`1.2f` is a `float` (4 bytes).

[More details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Any literal number in your code which includes a decimal point is interpreted as a `double`, not a `float`, unless you mark it as a `float` by appending `f`.

Doubles are not *automatically* converted to floats, since this can result in a loss of precision.

To fix your code, you can either:

- mark your literal number as a float:

  `Program obj1 = new Program(1.2f);`
- or, explicitly cast it as a float:

  `Program obj1 = new Program((float)1.2);`

The former option should be preferred when using a numeric literal, but if you are passing a variable typed as a double, then you can use the latter one.

Comment: The loss of precision is no worse than occurs with a typical `float` operation (e.g. computing 1.0f/10.0f).  The problem is simply that .net follows Java's backward rules, which require an explicit cast to go from the more specific type to the less specific type (notwithstanding that every `double` value can be represented in `float`, even if only as a value meaning e.g. "exceeding 2^128"), but does not require a cast to go from the less specific type to the more specific type (notwithstanding the fact that the compiler has to arbitrarily guess that the extra bits should be zero).